# TypeORM how to access a relation table directly?

Tags: typeorm, relation

How can I access a relation table in TypeORM DIRECTLY and do Queries on that Table?

```
LIKE SELECT * from movies_owner WHERE ownerID = 1;
```

To check if owner 1 even owns a single movie.

Notice the table does just exist on the Database and not as an Entity.

How can I access the table in TypeORM?

Comment: So basically, you want to use an ORM without an ORM? :confused:

Comment: I dont really WANT to, but it seems that this is the fastest and easiest way for me to get what I want...